# ERROR TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.from is not a function

Tags: angular, redux, observable

i have problem when use @select() and async pipe
I download course https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5433232 and at 6 lesson i found this problem, before it all works.[image]
.............................................................................................................................................................
app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgRedux, select} from 'ng2-redux';
import {IAppState} from './store';
import {INCREMENT} from './actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: 'app';
  @select() counter;

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
  }

  increment() {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: INCREMENT});
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<p>Counter: {{counter | async}}</p>

<button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
```

app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {NgReduxModule, NgRedux} from 'ng2-redux';
import {IAppState, INITIAL_STATE, rootReducer} from './store';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    NgReduxModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {
    ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  }
}
```

actions.ts

```
export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
```

store.ts

```
import {INCREMENT} from './actions';

export interface IAppState {
  counter: number;
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
  counter: 0
};

export function rootReducer(state: IAppState, action): IAppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return {counter: state.counter + 1};
  }
  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two suggested workarounds:

A) Override TypeScript compiler options.
Add the path section below to compilerOptions in src/tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "rxjs/internal/Observable": [
                "../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

B) Pin RxJS version at 6.2.x
You can lock your application to the unaffected 6.2.x version of rxjs by issuing the following command:

```
npm install --save rxjs@6.2 rxjs-compat@6.2
```